# Getting certain pandas dataframe results in a loop statement

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
date        close    code
2015-01-13  138.260  110037
2015-01-14  139.810  110037
2015-01-15  139.840  110037
2015-01-19  139.460  313046
2020-02-26  115.551  313046
2020-02-27  116.000  313046
2020-02-21  118.900  128094
2020-02-24  118.100  128094
2020-02-25  116.612  128094
```

Here is the dataframe sorted by 'code' and 'date'. How to write a for loop statement which only takes one 'code' data each time.

```
date        close    code
2015-01-13  138.260  110037
2015-01-14  139.810  110037
2015-01-15  139.840  110037
```

I tried by using `df.pivot_table(values='close', index=['code', 'date'])` but unable to locate 'code' index.

```
                     close
code    date               
110037  2015-01-13  138.260
        2015-01-14  139.810
        2015-01-15  139.840
113046  2015-01-19  139.460
        2020-02-26  115.551
        2020-02-27  116.000
128094  2020-02-21  118.900
        2020-02-24  118.100
        2020-02-25  116.612
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with some function if want processing data by unique `code`s:

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    #processing
    return x

df = df.groupby('code').apply(func)
```

Loop solution is:

```
for name, g in df.groupby('code'):
    print (name)
    print (g)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a for loop for Dataframes. But if you want to, you can use iterrows() function and check for 'code' data each time.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

You could also use loc()

```
df.loc[df['code']==110037]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html